# Minecraft Java Plugin - How do I remove all stored blocks in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, minecraft

I am trying to store all blocks being placed during game and then when I either run the command resetblocks or if the game is no longer running all the blocks I stored in the HashMap will be removed.

This is how I store my blocks. I just don't know how I can loop through the HashMap and destroy every block.

```
public HashMap<Block, Location> BlockReset = new HashMap<>();
// WHEN PLACED BLOCK
public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
    Block block = event.getBlock();
    Location location = block.getLocation();

    if (gameRunning == true) {
        BlockReset.put(block, location);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html.  Here's the Java tutorial about maps: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html. Do some basic research, and try something.

Comment: Im asking about making minecraft plugins and how to loop through this particular hashmap since I cant find this particular thing. I shouldn't add the Java tag since with it this post only attracts Java peeps and no one who can help me with my specific problem... :(

Comment: A HashMap is a HashMap is a HashMap. You iterate through the entries of a HashMap the same way, whether the map contains Minecraft blocks, bananas or anything else. You should just learn to read documentation, and to listen to Java peeps.

Comment: Please disregard my previous answer, if you saw it before I deleted it - it wouldn't work. Thanks JB Nizet for noticing that, it was a stupid mistake on my part to not check whether it was Iterable beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know things about minecraft, i checked javadoc about Block interface and don't find delete method or something like this. I think you know better how to handle this. Instead i help you with Map:

```
class Plugin {
    private Map<Block, Location> blocks = new HashMap<>();

    public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
        Block block = event.getBlock();
        Location location = block.getLocation();
        if (gameRunning == true) {
            blocks.put(block, location);
        }
    }

    public removeAllBlocks() {
        for(Map.Entry<Block, Location> entry : blocks.entrySet()) {
            Block block = entry.getKey();
            Location location entry.getValue();
            block.    // do what do you want with block and location
            location. // block.delete() or other minecraft things
        }
        blocks.clear(); //removes all entries from map, now map is clear;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a HashMap for saving and destroying the blocks subsequently because just the location matters.

Create a `List<Location>` and do it this way:

```
class Plugin {

    private List<Location> blocks = new ArrayList<>();

    public void onPlace(BlockPlaceEvent event) {
        Block block = event.getBlock();
        Location loc = block.getLocation();

        if (gameRunning == true) {
            if (!blocks.contains(loc))
                blocks.add(loc);
        }
    }

    public void destroyPlacedBlocks() {
        for (Location loc : blocks) {
            loc.getWorld().getBlockAt(loc).setType(Material.AIR);
        }
    }
}
```

Sincerely